# Input with responsive width and two buttons in a row

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm looking for a way to have a text input and two buttons next two each other, with the buttons taking as much horizontal space as they need and the input taking the remaining space. I'd also like to have small margins between the elements and I' prefer to achieve this using Bootstrap 4 classes.

I hoped I could use three `col-auto` divs, but this way the input gets a fixed with of about 150px:

```
<!-- Input. This should be as wide as possible. -->
<div class='col-auto'>
    <input class='form-control'
           type='text'>
</div>

<!-- 1st button -->
<div class='col-auto'>
    <button class='btn btn-primary'>
        DO that
    </button>
</div>

<!-- 2nd button -->
<div class='col-auto'>
    <button class='btn btn-primary'>
        Do that
    </button>
</div>
```

Is there an elegant way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you are using the lastest Bootstrap CSS CDN Link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Next, here is the code, try this out:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- 1st button -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-auto'>
        <button class='btn btn-primary'>Do This</button>
      </div>

      <!-- 2nd button -->
      <div class='col-auto'>
        <button class='btn btn-primary'>Do This</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Input. This should be as wide as possible. -->
      <div class='col w-100'>
        <input class='form-control' type='text'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In summary, use container-fluid, and then row, then use col-auto on the buttons, and col and w-100 on the input.

Comment: Thanks, combining `col` and `w-100` did the trick. This also works with `container` instead of `container-fluid`.

Answer (score 0):

U can make a Bootstrap grid with a single row and 3 columns, two of the same size and one with a larger size. 
I make this example code, try it out

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" >
        <input class='form-control'
           type='text' >
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" >
        <button class='btn btn-primary' style="width: 100%;">
            DO that
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button class='btn btn-primary' style="width: 100%;">
            DO that
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This renders three columns, the first one being twice as wide as the other two. But that's not what I need, see Andrew's answer.